# Object Mouse Event is displayed instead of number

Tags: javascript, html

There probably is a very simple solution so sorry in advance. I am trying to get a section on the webpage to update the number of moves. Now instead i get this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j997Y.png). It displays object mouse event instead. Any ideas how I could get around this?

```
//add an event listener to all classes name cardfront
    var moveCounter = document.getElementsByClassName("cardfront");
    var numberOfMoves = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < moveCounter.length; i++) {
    moveCounter[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        numberOfMoves += 1;
        console.log(numberOfMoves);
    });
}

//display number of moves every time a user clicks
document.addEventListener("click", function(numberOfMoves) {
    //remove element before updating to new element
    var element = document.getElementById("moves");
    var oldBoldBox = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0];//first b element. if there is any other b elements added this needs to change
    element.removeChild(oldBoldBox);

    //updates the move count by creating a new element
    var boldBox = document.createElement("b");
    var newLine = document.createTextNode("Moves: " + numberOfMoves);
    boldBox.appendChild(newLine);
    element.appendChild(boldBox);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the callback function parameter to something else, for example `event`:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
```